# getting into Safe Stack got a dotnet tool restore Error

Tags: .net, f#

I am getting into safeStack and ran into this error following the docs [here](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/)

```
$ dotnet tool restore
Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'tool' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      A compatible installed .NET SDK for global.json version [5.0.100] from [/home/nom/Desktop/f# port/global.json] was not found.
      Install the [5.0.100] .NET SDK or update [/home/nom/Desktop/f# port/global.json] with an installed .NET SDK:
        3.1.416 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
        6.0.101 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

**A-Pre-requisites are installed as in the readme**

```
You'll need to install the following pre-requisites in order to build SAFE applications

* [.NET Core SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download) 5.0 or higher
* [Node LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
```

**B-[/home/nom/Desktop/f# port/global.json] exists**

**C-suspecting: The application 'tool' does not exist.**

but no idea what it means.

> -new to f# and -no clue about dotnet,
> -path error?,
> -Devuan Beowulf 3.0.0,
> -help is appreciated.

Comment: It's `dotnet restore`, not `dotnet tool restore`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin tool restore is to restore tools, not normal nuget packages

Answer (score 2):

You need to either

1. delete global.json
2. change global.json to require SDK 6.x
3. change global.json to allow roll-forward major versions
4. install SDK 5.x

The readme and the code seem to be out of sync.

Edit: the [docs](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/) have been updated to say you need SDK 5 and node >= 8